# Why are form labels wrapping?

Tags: html, css

Attached is a minimal example of a web page I am working on. My goal is to have the form labels take up exactly the width they need to be able to display the text without wrapping, and for the rest of the 300px width of the div to be taken up by the image (which is much larger than 300px). I'm struggling to understand why the form is taking a seemingly arbitrary width and I would really like to understand how this works.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5zB.jpg" alt="" srcset="" />
  <form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Fruit</legend>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="red" name="top" value="red" checked />
        <label for="red">Red</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="blue" name="top" value="blue" checked />
        <label for="blue">
          BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue 
          BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="green" name="top" value="green" checked />
        <label for="green">GreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreen</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Veg</legend>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="red2" name="top" value="red" checked />
        <label for="red2">Red</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="blue2" name="top" value="blue" checked />
        <label for="blue2">
          BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue
          BlueBlueBlue BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="green2" name="top" value="green" checked />
        <label for="green2">GreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreen</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Checkout" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: this will never work: all your radio have the same name!

Comment: It's not arbitrary. It's attempting to fit your longest words within the 300px constraint you've give it. What else would you expect? What behavior do you actually want with those long words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily at least stop the wrapping with the below code:

```
label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5zB.jpg" alt="" srcset="" />
  <form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Fruit</legend>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="red" name="top" value="red" checked />
        <label for="red">Red</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="blue" name="top" value="blue" checked />
        <label for="blue">
          BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue 
          BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="green" name="top" value="green" checked />
        <label for="green">GreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreen</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Veg</legend>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="red2" name="top" value="red" checked />
        <label for="red2">Red</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="blue2" name="top" value="blue" checked />
        <label for="blue2">
          BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue
          BlueBlueBlue BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" id="green2" name="top" value="green" checked />
        <label for="green2">GreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreen</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Checkout" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
form {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Color</legend>
      <div class="wrap">
        <input type="radio" id="red" name="top" value="red" checked />
        <label for="red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla maximus ipsum erat, eu convallis odio accumsan a. Proin faucibus, quam non bibendum scelerisque, mi eros aliquam nisl, et porttitor mi mi ut ligula. Etiam id nisi enim.</label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Checkout" />
  </form>
```

This will do, don't forget to define a fixed width, or a max-width.

You can use anything instead of fieldset.

```
  fields {
      width: 300px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you're looking for. Simple container DIV using display "table-row" and two "table-cell" content divs. The form content is set not to wrap and the image content will automatically resize based on the available width remaining.

```css
#main-content {
        display: table-row;
        max-width: 100vw;
    }
    #img-content {
        display: table-cell;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #img-content img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    #form-content {
        display: table-cell;;
        padding: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align: middle;
        
    }
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="img-content">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5zB.jpg" alt="" srcset="" />
  </div>
  <div id="form-content">
    <form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Fruit</legend>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="red" name="top" value="red" checked />
          <label for="red">Red</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="blue" name="top" value="blue" checked />
          <label for="blue">
              BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue 
              BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="green" name="top" value="green" checked />
          <label for="green">GreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreen</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Veg</legend>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="red2" name="top" value="red" checked />
          <label for="red2">Red</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="blue2" name="top" value="blue" checked />
          <label for="blue2">
              BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue
              BlueBlueBlue BlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlueBlue
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" id="green2" name="top" value="green" checked />
          <label for="green2">GreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreenGreen</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Checkout" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```